# ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column CHAR

Tags: database, oracle

I'm pretty new to SQL Oracle and my class is going over Bulk Loading at the moment. I pretty much get the idea however I am having a little trouble getting it to read all of my records.

This is my SQL File;

```
PROMPT Creating Table 'CUSTOMER'
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(CustomerPhoneKey CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
,CustomerLastName VARCHAR(15)
,CustomerFirstName VARCHAR(15)
,CustomerAddress1 VARCHAR(15)
,CutomerAddress2 VARCHAR(30)
,CustomerCity VARCHAR(15)
,CustomerState VARCHAR(5)
,CustomerZip VARCHAR(5)
);
```

Quick and easy. Now This is my Control File to load in the data

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE Customer.dat
INTO TABLE Customer
FIELDS TERMINATED BY"|"
(CustomerPhoneKey, CustomerLastName, CustomerFirstName, CustomerAddress1 , CutomerAddress2, CustomerCity, CustomerState, CustomerZip)
```

Then the Data File

```
2065552123|Lamont|Jason|NULL|161 South Western Ave|NULL|NULL|98001
2065553252|Johnston|Mark|Apt. 304|1215 Terrace Avenue|Seattle|WA|98001
2065552963|Lewis|Clark|NULL|520 East Lake Way|NULL|NULL|98002
2065553213|Anderson|Karl|Apt 10|222 Southern Street|NULL|NULL|98001
2065552217|Wong|Frank|NULL|2832 Washington Ave|Seattle|WA|98002
2065556623|Jimenez|Maria|Apt 13 B|1200 Norton Way|NULL|NULL|98003
```

The problem is, that only the last record

```
2065556623|Jimenez|Maria|Apt 13 B|1200 Norton Way|NULL|NULL|98003
```

is being loaded in. The rest are in my bad file

So I took a look at my log file and the errors I'm getting are

> Record 1: Rejected - Error on table CUSTOMER, column CUSTOMERZIP.
>   ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column
>
> Record 2: Rejected - Error on table CUSTOMER, column CUSTOMERZIP.
>   ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column
>
> Record 3: Rejected - Error on table CUSTOMER, column CUSTOMERZIP.
>   ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column
>
> Record 4: Rejected - Error on table CUSTOMER, column CUSTOMERZIP.
>   ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column
>
> Record 5: Rejected - Error on table CUSTOMER, column CUSTOMERZIP.
>   ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column
>
> Table CUSTOMER:   1 Row successfully loaded.   5 Rows not loaded due
>   to data errors.   0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were
>   failed.   0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Onto the question. I see that CustomerZip is the problem, and initially I had it as CHAR(5) -- I did this because my understanding of the data type, is that for numeric values like a zip code, I would not be doing arithmetic operations with it, so it would be better to store it as CHAR. Also I did not use VARCHAR2 (5) initially, because seeing as it is a zip code, I don't want the value to vary, It should always be 5. Now maybe I'm just misunderstanding this. So if there is anyone that can clear that up, that would be awesome.

My second question, is "How do I fix this problem?" Given the above understanding of these data types, it doesn't make sense why CHAR(5) NOR VARCHAR2(5) work. As I am getting the same errors for both.

It makes even less sense that one record(the last one) actually works.

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: I should mention that I tried to go to office hours with my professor, however she was unable to identify the problem, and just instructed me do an entirely different table (basically ignore this problem and do an easier one). This seems pretty simple to me, and I'd like to actually know what I'm doing wrong, so that is why I turned to you guys

Comment: Did you create the data file in Windows, and run SQL\*Loader in Linux/Unix?

Comment: yes I ran the sqlldr in Unix

Answer (score 2):

Your data file has extra, invisible characters. We can't see the original but presumably it was created in Windows and has CRLF [new line separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline); and you're running SQL*Loader in a UNIX/Linux environment that is only expecting line feed (LF). The carriage return (CR) characters are still in the file, and Oracle is seeing them as part of the ZIP field in the file.

The last line doesn't have a CRLF (or any new-line marker), so on that line - and *only* that line - the ZIP field is being seen as 5 characters, For all the others it's being seen as six, e.g. `98001^M`.

You can read more about the default behaviour [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL984):

> - On UNIX-based platforms, if no terminator_string is specified, then SQL*Loader defaults to the line feed character, \n.
> - On Windows NT, if no terminator_string is specified, then SQL*Loader uses either \n or \r\n as the record terminator, depending on which one it finds first in the data file. This means that if you know that one or more records in your data file has \n embedded in a field, but you want \r\n to be used as the record terminator, then you must specify it.

If you open the data file in an edit like vi or vim, you'll see those extra `^M` control characters.

There are several ways to fix this. You can modify the file; the simplest thing to do that is copy and paste the data into a new file created in the environment you'll run SQL*Loader in. There are utilities to convert line endings if you prefer, e.g. `dos2unix`. Or your Windows editor may be able to save the file without the CRs. You could also add an extra field delimiter to the data file, as Ditto suggested.

Or you could tell SQL*Loader to expect CRLF by changing the `INFILE` line:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE Customer.dat "str '\r\n'"
INTO TABLE Customer
...
```

... though that will then cause problems if you do supply a file created in Linux, without the CR characters.

Comment: I think he could also add an extra pipe "|" after the final field, couldn't he? Oracle would then just ignore the "extra field" .. since it's not being listed to go anywhere. :)

Comment: Or he could just specify:  `RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline;`  ?? :) (still might not spot the extra CR/LF from windows though)

Comment: @Ditto - that's the default anyway, and it's the interpretation of NEWLINE that's the problem, I think...

Comment: Ok what you guys said definitely makes sense. So could I actually, remake the datafile and not enter any newlines? and just have it be one continuous line with '|' delimiters. Or can I add one of those "also delimited by newline" statements

Comment: well you need a way to tell it "hey this is a new record" ... that's (by default) a newline. In Windows: CR+LF .. in Unix just LF ...

Comment: @swash018 - I've added how you tell SQL\*Loader to expect CRLF instead of the default (for Linux) LF. I wouldn't put all the rows in one line in the file, but that might not be what you meant; you still need it to have line breaks (LF), but you can recreate it without the carriage returns (CR).

Comment: OK thank you all for the help. Since you pointed me in the right direction I was able to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Basically what I did, is opened up my .dat file in Notepad++ and there is an option for newer versions where you do EDIT > EOL CONVERSION > UNIX FORMAT > SAVE FILE. Doing that will get rid of the CRLFs and only keep the LFs for Unix. Thank you again everyone. Hope this helps others

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility, dos2unix, that is present on almost all UNIX machines.  If you run it, you can output the data file with the DOS/Windows CRLF combination stripped.