# SQL*Loader on Windows and Unix/Linux server

Tags: linux, windows, oracle, sql-loader

I prepared a control file to insert a text file as follow:

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
INFILE *
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE accounts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(   
COMPTEETA   "TRIM(:COMPTEETA)", 
COMPTEPLA   "TRIM(:COMPTEPLA)", 
COMPTECOM   "TRIM(:COMPTECOM)", 
COMPTEOBL   "TRIM(:COMPTEOBL)", 
COMPTEINT   "TRIM(:COMPTEINT)", 
COMPTEAGE   "TRIM(:COMPTEAGE)", 
COMPTEDEV   "TRIM(:COMPTEDEV)", 
COMPTEOUV   "TRIM(:COMPTEOUV)", 
COMPTECLO   "TRIM(:COMPTECLO)", 
COMPTELOR   "TRIM(:COMPTELOR)", 
COMPTESUC   "TRIM(:COMPTESUC)", 
COMPTECLA   "TRIM(:COMPTECLA)", 
COMPTEFON   "TRIM(:COMPTEFON)", 
COMPTEBLO   "TRIM(:COMPTEBLO)", 
COMPTEMOT   "TRIM(:COMPTEMOT)", 
COMPTESEN   "TRIM(:COMPTESEN)", 
COMPTEMOD   "TRIM(:COMPTEMOD)"
)
```

Running its corresponding SQL*Loader on Windows (`.bat` file)

```
@ECHO OFF
sqlldr user/pass@DB data=accounts.txt  control=accounts.ctl log=accounts.log
```

it will end successfully. But when trying the same control file and executing  `.sh` file) on a Linux server:

```
${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlldr user/pass@DB data=path/accounts.txt \
  control=path/accounts.ctl log=path/accounts.log bad=path/accounts.bad
```

it will end with errors, no records are inserted and for reason:

```
  Record 1: Rejected - Error on table SSDX_IN.accounts, column COMPTEMOD.
  ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Similar for the next 50 records. Checking data type, path, separator, etc ... and all is correct.

Why can the file be loaded using `.bat` and not when using `.sh`?

Comment: What does the data look like? Do the Windows and Linux environments have the same NLS_LANG setting? (I'm *guessing* they don't, and specifically have different NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS as a result, which would cause problems converting string to numbers is they contain group and/or decimal separators).

Comment: @AlexPoole, 1 1 0080EUR5555000011121 4232101115 XXXXXXXXX 80 EUR 1050604 0  N 1 0 0   1160827
1 1 0080USD5555500001121 4232101115 XXXXXXXXX 80 USD 1110711 0  N 1 0 0   1160827

Comment: Please edit the question and add that, formatted; it doesn't look like there are enough fields there to match the control file? Unless there are multiple tabs that aren't showing up. Are any of the values in the 17th field (COMPTEMOD) have periods or commas?

Comment: @AlexPoole,  Yes before COMPTEMOD(value 1160827)  there is 2 nullable columns and the field COMPTEMOD does not contain any period or comma

Comment: Please put the file data into the question. Possibly in pastebin or similar as well in case original formatting info is still lost. <strike>Copying and pasting from your comment there are Unicode zero-width non-joiner and space characters (200c and 200b) which may be part of the problem</strike> (never mind; seems to be [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970/152099)). I still don't see enough columns though. Also has the text file been modified to remove the CR characters if it moved from Windows to Linux? It might be that simple - you left the CR at the end of each line of data??

Comment: If that is the problem, then [this is possibly a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36408874/266304)?