# SQL loader ORA-01722 issue

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using the below ctl to load data to a staging table via a .csv file.

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
REPLACE
INTO TABLE NCR_CTB_SAFETY_STOCK
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
SS_NAME     ,
SS_PID          ,
SS_TARGET_QTY   ,
CREATED_BY              "-1",
CREATION_DATE           sysdate,
LAST_UPDATED_BY         "-1",
LAST_UPDATED_DATE       sysdate,
LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN       "-1"
)
```

Below is the .csv file.

```
SS_Name,SS_PID,SS_Target_Qty
ALHA,1614C6,2
AOHA,1615C18,76
AA,1618C11,12
```

And the table definition:

```
create table NCR_CTB_SAFETY_STOCK (
  SS_NAME VARCHAR2(1000),
  SS_PID VARCHAR2(1000),
  SS_TARGET_QTY NUMBER,
  CREATED_BY NUMBER,
  CREATION_DATE DATE,
  LAST_UPDATED_BY NUMBER,
  LAST_UPDATED_DATE DATE,
  LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN NUMBER
)
```

When I run the SQL loader command from server no rows are inserted in the table and we get the below error.

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table NCR_CTB_SAFETY_STOCK, column SS_TARGET_QTY.
ORA-01722: invalid number

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table NCR_CTB_SAFETY_STOCK, column SS_TARGET_QTY.
ORA-01722: invalid number

Record 3: Rejected - Error on table NCR_CTB_SAFETY_STOCK, column SS_TARGET_QTY.
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Could anyone suggest what can we do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Post CREATE TABLE command as well.

Comment: create table NCR_CTB_SAFETY_STOCK 
(SS_NAME                 VARCHAR2(1000) ,
SS_PID                  VARCHAR2(1000) ,
SS_TARGET_QTY           NUMBER         ,
CREATED_BY              NUMBER         ,
CREATION_DATE           DATE           ,
LAST_UPDATED_BY         NUMBER         ,
LAST_UPDATED_DATE       DATE           ,
LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN       NUMBER );

Comment: @GauravThuckral - with your table, CSV and control file I got three rows loaded successfully. So... are you maybe running this on a Unix/Linux server, and using a CSV from Windows, with carriage return characters on the end of each line? That would cause this error. If so, it's essentially [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36408874/266304).

Comment: Yes Alex i'm running on a unix server.what can i do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Remove the carriage returns, or change the control file to handle them; see the answers on the question I linked to.

Comment: Hey Alex thanks for the info i was able to resolve the issue by using INFILE * "str '\r\n'". Just want to know is it alright to use * as file name ?

Comment: `*` means [the data is within the file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-7EBEA709-4192-4B5A-A3FA-450D41BE2EC7), so presumably that loaded zero rows; but without any errors.

Comment: As an aside, why try to initialize 'last updated by', etc. with "-1".  Trying to use "magic values" just makes for a more complex environment when a default of NULL means the same thing.

Comment: Alex thanks got it !!! EdStevens could you please elaborate on "magic values" or perhaps provide a document for its application.